# Drupal include external class

Tags: drupal, mailchimp

I want to use the MailChimp API class in my Drupal module and I don't know how can I include it in my module. I've added the class in `sites/all/libraries` and I cannot include it via `drupal_get_path()`. What's the *Drupal* way to include an external library?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Why don't you simply use [MailChimp](http://drupal.org/project/mailchimp) module for Drupal?!

**UPDATED**

If it's not for you, then try to implement the same method as in [MailChimp](http://drupal.org/project/mailchimp) module.

1) Add MailChimp class in your module folder, let's say it's `MailChimp.class.php`.

2) In your module add the following:

```
/**
 * Get a Mailchimp API object for communication with the mailchimp server.
 */
function mailchimp_get_api_object() {
  $q = new MailChimp();
  // You can add different parameters and validations for your class here
  return $q;
}
```

As you noticed class name should be same as class file name (`.class.php` should be added because Drupal will find class file automatically).

Comment: I only need a couple of calls on the API object and I find it pointless to add the whole module only for this.

Comment: Thanks. I was looking to include the API from the libraries folder, but I've gone with this approach. Thanks :)

Comment: You can include it from libraries, but you'll need to add [Libraries API](http://drupal.org/project/libraries) module to search for your library or you can simply copy some functions from `Libraries API` into your module.